# Bootstrap 3 - data-container changing tooltip custom css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I have a custom css to a particular tooltip using Bootstrap 3 and in order to avoid troubles when rendering, I had to put the `data-container="body"` attribute. It fixed the rendering problem, but my css is not working anymore. My problem here is specifically about the correct css seletor to make my css work again.

The HTML element is

```
<i data-toggle="tooltip" title="${item}" data-placement="top" class="custom-tooltip material-icons" data-container="body">insert_comment</i>
```

My original css is:

```
.custom-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    //My changes
}
```

I have tried `.custom-tooltip[data-container="body"] + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner`, `[data-container="body"].custom-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner` but is not working. I know it's a very basic question, but I'm stuck. I really apreciate any help.

Comment: Where is `.tooltip > .tooltip-inner` HTML?

Comment: That's curious, it works here. You have some confliction or overide occuring.

    .custom-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {color: #f00;}

http://jsfiddle.net/ckxSs/16/

Comment: It seems like popover has a bit more functionality, you might check that out. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/

Comment: @m4n0 Bootstrap add .tooltip-inner by itself

Comment: @HeatherNew if you add `data-container` attribute, it will stop working

Comment: I don't think data-container can be used on tooltip which is why I suggest using popover and modifying it to fit your content.

Comment: @HeatherNew I'm going to uso popover, it's more similar to what I was find for